# Computing difference by comparing nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I was under the impression that array_diff evaluates the difference between the values in the two arrays. But somehow it doesn't work...I am guessing nested arrays is the problem here. Clearly array_diff_assoc is not the solution as keys are irrelevant in this case.

I don't even want to make it go nested, just see whether the value (in this case, array) inside are identical or not.

```
$file_details = array(
    array(
            "uuid" => "45ebdbaa-380b-483b-80a2-73d7c53088e2",
            "filename" => "train_failure.mp3",
        ),
    array("uuid" => "97baa061-4208-4aeb-8136-eb76c0932a3d",
        "filename" => "train_work1.mp3"
    ),
    array("uuid" => "ksjdfls6-eb76c0932a3d",
        "filename" => "train.mp3"
    ),
);

$items = array(
    array(
            "uuid" => "45ebdbaa-380b-483b-80a2-73d7c53088e2",
            "filename" => "train_failure.mp3",
        ),
     array(
            "uuid" => "1233489eb76c0932a3d",
            "filename" => "train.mp3"
        ),
);

print_r(array_diff($file_details,$items));
```

This returns an empty array...How should I go about fixing this?

My desired output is

```
array(
        "uuid" => "97baa061-4208-4aeb-8136-eb76c0932a3d",
        "filename" => "train_work1.mp3"
     ),
array(
        "uuid" => "ksjdfls6-eb76c0932a3d",
        "filename" => "train.mp3"
    ),
```

UPDATE -: *I know array_diff doesn't work for 1-d array, I'm just surprised there is no direct php function for doing a comparison on multidimensional arrays.*

Comment: See documentation for *array_diff*. There's an answer for your question. You can also try *array_udiff*.

Comment: @ghaxx - I know array_diff doesn't work for 1-d array, I'm just surprised there is no direct php function for doing a comparison on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Patrik: I though you'll find there the comment with a the trick for comparing 2D arrays using serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array items are arrays and cannot be compared as strings (`array_diff()` will treat all values as strings - for example, it will try to stringify objects via calling their `__toString()` method).

You can use [array_udiff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) instead:

```
$rgResult=array_udiff($file_details, $items, function($rgX, $rgY)
{
   return $rgX['uuid']<$rgY['uuid']?-1:$rgX['uuid']!=$rgY['uuid'];
});
```

Comment: Cheers...Very surprised php doesn't give a direct function to compare even nested arrays.

Comment: That is opinion-based. I think that's ok, because array could contain anything and to say that first is less/greater/equal to second is not easy in common case

Answer (score 1):

`array_diff()` method is supposed to work with 1-d array.

Answer (score 0):

From the array_diff() man page:

> Note:
>
> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of
>   course you can check deeper dimensions by using
>
> array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);